# Date time axis on zoom band chart of LigtningChart JS

Tags: javascript, lightningchart

In zoom band chart of Lightning chart JS i need to show date time on axis x of zoom band chart but it showing me mill seconds.
kindly refer image to understand my issue.
date time showing proper on XY chart but not on zoom band chart.
Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Please use ZoomBandChart.getDefaultAxisX() to get the rebellious axis and also use setTickStrategy() to set it to use DateTime ticks.

```
zoomBandChart.getDefaultAxisX().setTickStrategy(AxisTickStrategies.DateTime)
```

Comment: It worked thanks pal

Comment: How to set ->
zoomBandChart.band.setValueStart() 
and 
zoomBandChart.band.setValueEnd() value for datetime ?

Comment: Well i have solved it by applying following code --------------------------------------------------`var endrange = new Date().getTime() - dateOrigin.getTime();
                var startrange = new Date(new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear() - 1)).getTime() - dateOrigin.getTime();
                zoomBandChart.band.setValueStart(startrange)
                zoomBandChart.band.setValueEnd(endrange)`

Comment: You're on the right track - Use Date.getTime() to get numbers from dates.